# Facing issue in action function

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

I've this simple VF page, which is populating today's date on change of value of Picklist(Active__c field as mentioned below):
This is done with help of action function which refreshes an outputText.  But it is not working.  its gives error : 
Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores. 
Does using extention anything to do with it?

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="RefeshCon">

  <script type = "Text/Javascript">
  function PopulateDate()
  { 
    alert('hi');
   ActPopulateDate();
  }
  </script>
  <apex:form > 
    <apex:ActionFunction name="ActPopulateDate" action="{!populatedateviaCont}" reRender="Refreshdate" />
    <apex:pageblock >
     <apex:pageblockSection >
       <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
       <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Active__c}" onchange="PopulateDate()" />
       <apex:outputText value="{!d}" id="Refreshdate" />
     </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

This is my controller

```
public class RefeshCon {

    public datetime d {get;set;}

    public RefeshCon(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }
    public pagereference populatedateviaCont() {
        d = system.now();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the page not working at all, or only when you change the input field? What is the name of your visualforce page?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, Picklist `Active__c` field gets updated with today's date whenever there's any activity on in the account. From the error message you're getting, it sounds like `Active__c` is text field.

```
 <apex:pageblockSection >
   <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
   <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Active__c}" onchange="PopulateDate()" />
   <apex:outputText value="{!d}" id="Refreshdate" />
```

That means when you run the code below, you need to get the string value of the DateTime using `string.valueOf()` on `system.now()` as shown below. `System.now()`is a `datetime` field and will include the date, as well as time including minutes, seconds, time zone, etc. :

```
public string d {set;} // you only need to set this value, not get it too

public pagereference populatedateviaCont() {
    d = string.valueOf(System.now()); 
    return null;
}
```